# Multiple Sphero in AR

Tags: sphero-api

How well does the Sphero AR handle multiple Sphero at this point?  Are they capable of meshing their locator grids so as to have the same 'map' be shared between the two?  I was thinking perhaps, such as in Rolling Dead, that the phone camera could briefly mark multiple Sphero so as to set them up under the same grid by calculating their position in relation to each other, the player, and a center point as designated by the player (as with the cupcakes in Sharky).  I program for Android, so I'm unable to test this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sphero AR SDK currently does not support more than one Sphero.